# Is it possible to combinate .Java with .Jar to make one .Jar?

Tags: java, compilation

Actually I have :

Modify.java
commons-io-2.4.jar

And when I compile I must everytime specify that I use commons-io-2.4.jar like :

```
javac -cp .;lib\commons-io-2.4.jar Modify.java
```

Is there a way that I run my program like this :

```
java MyProgram.jar
```

Comment: You have to package your jar with dependencies just google it.

Comment: you acan add the commons-io jar to your classpath. so that it gets used everytime you compile and run without having to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Why are you not using an IDE or a build tool?  In an IDE you can run a program with one button and if you what to deploy this, a build tool can create a single jar from many jars and setup your `Main-Class` as well.

Comment: @55597 he IS adding the jar to the classpath, that's what the -cp switch does. You are referring to the CLASSPATH environmental variable. That is not "the classpath", it is a rather outdated and easily conflicting way to not have to use a build tool, an IDE or to create a shell script.

Comment: Actually I am quite confused; what is the real question here? Is this question about not having to specify the classpath when compiling, or about running a jar file? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

Compile you `.java` file and get the `.class` file.
add `.class` file in correct **package** folder inside `.jar` file.
It should work.

Or unjar the existing jar. Add new .class file to correct folder hierachy.
Re-jar using

> jar cf jar-file input-file(s)

Make sure you use the correct archive format [java archive]